# Update a sharepoint Contact List via Outlook

Tags: sharepoint-server

We have SharePoint 2016 on-prem.
We have created a Contact List and added few other [columns].

Next, we connect the Contact List with the Outlook client.
However, when I create a New Contact via Outlook, I do not get all the fields!

[image]

Why is that? Is this a normal behaviour 
More importantly, how can I add those extra fields to the New Contact form in Outlook?

I mean, by this method: it seems to be only one way process.
Meaning, to new contact > need to go to SharePoint List.

Please advise, what else can be done here.
Is there a way to add those fields into the Outlook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the expected behavior that custom columns from SharePoint list **do not** get synced to Outlook Contact form. The form itself needs to be customized in Outlook client. (Sample process [here](https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/10-things/10-easy-steps-to-customizing-an-outlook-2010-form/).)

The OOB fields from *Core contact and Calendar Columns* group in SharePoint can be used and synced directly (not to the New Contact form) since they already exist in Outlook.

It is better to use custom fields in Outlook and sync it back to SharePoint instead.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense :)